# Lombok @Log4j2 annotation doesn't work with latest version of log4j (v2.15.0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I upgraded the log4j dependency to the latest 2.15.0 version and now my Spring Boot application throws an error on start up

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.<clinit>(ConfigurationSource.java:56)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:85)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
    at foo.bar.org.MyApp.<clinit>(MyApp.java:13)
```

Here is my main class

```
@Log4j2
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried use this log inside this class for checking is logging? `log.info("anything");`

Comment: Downgrade and create bug report with the Lombok developers.

Comment: I highly doubt this has anything to do with lombok. Lombok just generates a LogManager.getLogger invocation. This sounds like you've mixed versions in your dependency stack. Run `java -jar lombok.jar delombok -p YourSourceFile.java` and then try to compile that ,which will confirm for you that lombok isn't the problem here. Or just check the docs - `@Log4j2` just generates a one-liner.

Comment: How did you upgrade to Log4j 2.15.0?

Answer (score 10):

In case you have the following in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

make sure that both have the same version. I forgot it for one (left the old version) and saw the same error.

Comment: Solved problem with Sonarqube

Answer (score 6):

1. set the log4j2.version property:

```
<properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>
```

2. fix pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. it helped me

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to exclude all transitive dependencies of conflicting version for **log4j-api** and **log4j-core**. 
I've tracked them down with: 
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api` 
and 
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core` 
 So I made sure that **2.15.0** version was the only version for both log4j dependencies across the project.

Answer (score 0):

Our old project have the same problem with 2.15.0or 2.16.0 ,then we try 2.12.2 is ok,and this also fix the security vulnerability。
here the log4j site:https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

> **Mitigation**
>
> In version 2.12.2 Log4j disables access to JNDI by default. Usage of JNDI in configuration now need to be enabled explicitly. Calls to the JndiLookup will now return a constant string. Also, Log4j now limits the protocols by default to only java. The message lookups feature has been completely removed.
>
> In version 2.16.0 Log4j disables access to JNDI by default. JNDI lookups in configuration now need to be enabled explicitly. Also, Log4j now limits the protocols by default to only java, ldap, and ldaps and limits the ldap protocols to only accessing Java primitive objects. Hosts other than the local host need to be explicitly allowed. The message lookups feature has been completely removed.